# Why can't you click on your location in your profile to get a list of other developers on Stackoverflow in your area?

Tags: feature-request, community

I think this would be great for fostering local community. I mean not everybody can go to Dev Days ya know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Because** - and pay close attention here, because it's not terribly obvious and a *lot* of people make this mistake - *because*, Stack Overflow is **not** Facebook.

It *could* be, of course. Don't think for a minute that Atwood & Co. aren't perfectly capable of writing Facebook. But why would they opt for fame and untold riches, when they could instead provide a narrowly-scoped Q&A site for programmers?

Comment: Well I didn't mean like a facebook for programmers...just a way of finding out who else might be up for a code-camp in your area...

Comment: @leeand00: yeah, and that'd be fun and all, at least for those who were into it, but... that's not what SO is for. Different sites have different purposes - Facebook is for social networking, LinkedIn is more like *professional* networking, and SO? SO is a programming Q&A site.

Comment: @Shog9 Separation of concerns?

Comment: Well yeah that is definitely one thing I don't like about Facebook.  They don't separate their concerns well.  It's like they just tried to take the whole internet and jam it into one website.  Yeah I wouldn't want them to do that with Stackoverflow...

Comment: Separation of concerns - nice! :-)